# Prove that the sum of a trigonometric series has bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $u$: $(0,1)\to \mathbb R$ be defined as
$$ u(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cos(2^n\pi x)$$
I am trying to prove that $\operatorname{Var}(u)<\infty$

It is clear that $\operatorname{Var}(\frac{1}{2^n} \cos(2^n\pi x))=2$ but then I will have $\operatorname{Var} (u)\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2 =\infty$... dead end.....

I then try to define
$$u_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n} \cos(2^n\pi x)$$
and show that $\operatorname{Var}(u_N)$ is uniformly bounded, but I got nothing from this path too.

Comment: Partition your function carefully

Comment: Yea I tried it... but I have no (interval) monotonicity in summations...

Comment: @user124358 Do you accept that it converges to $0$?

Comment: why? for $x=0$ it convergence to $1$. For other points, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modified form of the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) with $a=1/2$ and $b=2$. As the classical Weierstrass functions (those with $ab>1+\frac32\pi$), this one is nowhere differentiable, but this fact is much harder. It was proved less than 100 years ago, by Hardy: the Wikipedia article has a reference.

Since the functions of bounded variation are differentiable a.e., this function is not of bounded variation.

Comment: hmm... So you are saying that this question is actually wrong...?

Comment: but here we have $ab=1$ not $ab>1+3/2\pi$, do we still have this function is nowhere differentiable?

Comment: That's what I said, referring to the article. Quote: *G. H. Hardy showed that the function of the above construction is nowhere differentiable with the assumptions $0 < a < 1$, $ab \ge 1$. [Here's the original paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1916-017-03/S0002-9947-1916-1501044-1/): see Theorem 1.31.

Comment: Thx, then I need to go back to check the original question...this is question 3.43 part $ii$ on Leoni's book with special case $p=1$. I do apologize if I misunderstand the original question...

Comment: You understood it correctly; the exercise is wrong, at least for $p=1$. I haven't thought about it much, but using self-similarity of the series, one should be able to prove that the variation is infinite in a more direct way.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "self-similarity" of the series? Thx!